# Twitter Streaming API not giving any results

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I'm running the following code to get tweets related to the below keywords.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

access_token = "K"
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status.text               

if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)


    stream.filter(track=["flyspicejet","jetairways","airindiain","goairlinesindia","airvistara","spicejet","airindia","goairlines","vistara"])
```

However I ran this for a few hours but got no results!How can it be possible that not even a single tweet with these keywords(popular airlines in India) was published?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you tried starting out with a single keyword? Manually searching Twitter to see if you should have expected any results?

Comment: Yes. I did. I even asked my friend to tweet. Also I left it on for a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You're not handing the error cases properly. Try the following code:

`Python 3` version:

```
import time
import argparse
import os
import sys
import json

#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from http.client import IncompleteRead


access_token = "acc token here"
access_token_secret = "acc token secret"
consumer_key = "consumer key"
consumer_secret = "consumer secret here"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    '''A basic listener that just writes received tweets to file.'''

    def __init__(self, outputfile):
        self.file = outputfile

    def on_data(self, data):
        with open(self.file, 'a') as ofile:
            #simply write everything to file as raw json
            ofile.write(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    requiredArgs = parser.add_argument_group('must need arguments')
    requiredArgs.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Output txt file to write tweets', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    filepath = os.getcwd() + os.path.sep + args.output
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        sys.exit("output file already exists; Give new filename!")
    else:
        #create an empty file
        open(args.output,'a').close()

    l = StdOutListener(args.output)
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    keyword_list = ['Computer Science', 'Cancer', 'Germany', 'Paris']

    while True:
        try:
            stream = Stream(auth, l)
            stream.filter(track=keyword_list, stall_warnings=True)

        except IncompleteRead as e:
            # Oh well, sleep sometime & reconnect and keep trying again
            time.sleep(15)
            continue

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            stream.disconnect()
            break
```